# How to configure FreeTDS to work with Ubuntu 16.04 PHP (MSSQL)

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, freetds, php-7

I have trouble to configure freetds to work with ubuntu server 16.04 which is using PHP7

The following code that I"m using return empty but using the same code on my another server running ubuntu server 14.04 is working fine.

```
 $myServer = "IPAddress";
 $myUser = "username";
 $myPass = "password";
 $myDB = "database"; 

 //connection to the database
 $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
     or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

 //select a database to work with
    mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle);
```

BUT... in the terminal after installing freetds and it work great! meaning to say freetds is correctly installed but PHP is not properly configure?

```
sqluser1@ubuntu1604:/etc/php/7.0/mods-available# tsql -S IPAddress -U sa
Password: 
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1> use database1
2> go
1> select top 2 custid from customer
2> go
custid
A00001         
A00002         
(2 rows affected)
1>
```

Some article suggest me to try the following method but it doesn't work for me

Install (Problem: php5-sybase is not available in ubuntu 16.04)

```
apt-get install libsybdb5 freetds-common php5-sybase
```

Edit php.ini (Problem: mssql.so is not exist)

```
; Enable the mssql extension
extension=mssql.so
```

Please advise and thanks

Comment: Per https://wiki.php.net/rfc/removal_of_dead_sapis_and_exts#extmssql, the mssql extension no longer exists. You need to use one of the alternatives. I think for linux the use of PDO ODBC is recommended.